# How to get the last date in custom interval? - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

May my example be a lot big,my code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io
t = """
name     date
a     2005-08-31
a     2005-09-20
a     2005-11-12
a     2005-12-31
a     2006-03-31
a     2006-06-25
a     2006-07-23
a     2006-09-28
a     2006-12-21
a     2006-12-27
a     2007-07-23
a     2007-09-21
a     2007-03-15
a     2008-04-12
a     2008-06-21
a     2008-06-11
b     2005-08-31
b     2005-09-23
b     2005-11-12
b     2005-12-31
b     2006-03-31
b     2006-06-25
b     2006-07-23
b     2006-09-28
b     2006-12-21
b     2006-12-27
b     2007-07-23
b     2007-09-21
b     2007-03-15
b     2008-04-12
b     2008-06-21
b     2008-06-11
"""
data=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),delimiter='     ')#5 space here
data
```

What I want to do is to find the every last day of the year which year begin`2005-7-1`) and end `2006-06-30` ,begin `2006-7-1` and end `2007-6-30`...and so on .
And my expected output is here:

```
name     date
a     2006-06-25  #the last day of the 2005/7/01 -2006/06/31
a     2007-03-15  #the last day of the 2006/7/01 -2007/06/31
a     2008-06-21  #the last day of the 2007/7/01 -2008/06/31
b     2006-06-25  #the last day of the 2005/7/01 -2006/06/31
b     2007-03-15  #the last day of the 2006/7/01 -2007/06/31
b     2008-06-21  #the last day of the 2007/7/01 -2008/06/31
```

How can fix this ? I think I should use the `custom`

Comment: Is is to long to read?

Comment: Note: September only has 30 days, so there is some bad data in there.

Comment: @AndyHayden My god,thanks to point it !

Comment: @BharathshettyThanks too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without the rollback using a single groupby:

```
In [11]: data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

In [12]: df.groupby(["name", pd.Grouper(key="date", freq="AS-JUL")])["date"].max()
Out[12]:
name  date
a     2005-07-01   2006-06-25
      2006-07-01   2007-03-15
      2007-07-01   2008-06-21
b     2005-07-01   2006-06-25
      2006-07-01   2007-03-15
      2007-07-01   2008-06-21
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I was using the freq and grouper the whole time din't know it can take offsets too. Super +1. I will remember this one

Comment: Adding as another answer, as it's pretty different (a lot shorter)!

Comment: I didn't know offset aliases. Now I got a stronger grip towards them. All i was doing was 3D , 5D ....

Comment: @Bharathshetty you should very familiar  with the method I use ~ :-)

Comment: Never mean to bother,But if I want the`[2015-7-02,2016-6-25]` as a custom year, how can I do this?

Comment: @Tangfeifan interesting, please ask a new question :) I am not sure at the moment, but if you ask as a new question I think someone will be able to answer :) (Just the "[2015-7-02,2016-6-25] as a custom year" part)

Comment: OK,I have been fix it ,just set the `freq=365` and specify the start and end ,is OK!Thanks for your help

Comment: @Tangfeifan no problem, feel free to link to a new question here if you make a new question!

Answer (score 4):

Well, this seems like a magical way!
The frequency is "AS-JUL" (which is year start frequency, starting in July).

We'll first take the beginning of each month (since you have some bad dates in there, let's just ignore them) but the critical thing is we need it to be datetime rather than string:

```
In [11]: pd.to_datetime(data.date.str[:7], format="%Y-%m")  # to beginning of month
Out[11]:
0    2005-08-01
1    2005-09-01
2    2005-11-01
3    2005-12-01
...

In [12]: df.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date.str[:7], format="%Y-%m")
```

Now here comes the [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963946/1240268):

```
In [13]: from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

In [14]: df.date.map(to_offset("AS-JUL").rollback)
Out[14]:
0    2005-07-01
1    2005-07-01
2    2005-07-01
3    2005-07-01
4    2005-07-01
5    2005-07-01
6    2006-07-01
7    2006-07-01
8    2006-07-01
9    2006-07-01
10   2007-07-01
11   2007-07-01
12   2006-07-01
13   2007-07-01
14   2007-07-01
15   2007-07-01
16   2005-07-01
17   2005-07-01
18   2005-07-01
19   2005-07-01
20   2005-07-01
21   2005-07-01
22   2006-07-01
23   2006-07-01
24   2006-07-01
25   2006-07-01
26   2007-07-01
27   2007-07-01
28   2006-07-01
29   2007-07-01
30   2007-07-01
31   2007-07-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

We created an offset to `"AS-JUL"` and rolled it back (meaning floor).
*Note: For whatever reason we can't use `dt.floor`...*

---

Okay, misread this part, you want the latest recorded date for each group in each period, with the corrected dates, the last part is just a groupby:

```
In [21]: data.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")

In [22]: data["period_start"] = data.date.map(to_offset("AS-JUL").rollback).dt.normalize()

In [23]: data.groupby(["name", "period_start"])["date"].max()
Out[23]:
name  period_start
a     2005-07-01     2006-06-25
      2006-07-01     2007-03-15
      2007-07-01     2008-06-21
b     2005-07-01     2006-06-25
      2006-07-01     2007-03-15
      2007-07-01     2008-06-21
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Well these are really new for me

Comment: @Bharathshetty new to me also, very neat trick (the "magic" is from the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45963946/1240268)). For the other offsets see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35339226/1240268.

Comment: I loved the solution but the answer OP is looking for I think is different. He want to find last working day in the interval I think. We need groupby then check for the max date by creating an interval index I think

Comment: @Bharathshetty oh no!!

Comment: @Bharathshetty I will modify, the trick gets you most of the way there.

Comment: Yeah@Bharathshetty is right! I need to find the last day in the intervalu !

Comment: Even I came up with almost same thing I think

Comment: @Bharathshetty there's a better trick, see my other answer :)

Comment: @AndyHayden [Here is the new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871173/how-can-i-astype-the-freq-as-what-i-want)

Answer (score 3):

From the beautiful function `to_offset` @Andy suggested we can do

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset
new = data.groupby('name').apply(lambda x : x.groupby(x['date'].map(to_offset("AS-JUL"))).max())
```

```
             name       date
name date                      
a    2006-07-01    a 2006-06-25
     2007-07-01    a 2007-03-15
     2008-07-01    a 2008-06-21
b    2006-07-01    b 2006-06-25
     2007-07-01    b 2007-03-15
     2008-07-01    b 2008-06-21
```

Comment: You both do great but I just can accept one ,so I will accept the faster one Andy,but also thanks you very much!

Comment: Even I will feel bad if you dont accept his solution.

Answer (score 3):

By using `IntervalIndex`(`DF` is your `DataFrame`)

```
idx=pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(pd.date_range(start='2005-07-01',freq='12MS',periods=12),pd.date_range(start='2006-06-30',freq='12M',periods=12),closed='both')
df=pd.DataFrame({'G':list(range(len(idx)))},index=idx)
DF.date=pd.to_datetime(DF.date)
DF['G']=df.loc[DF.date].values
DF.sort_values(['name','date']).drop_duplicates(['name','G'],keep='last')

Out[19]: 
   name       date  G
5     a 2006-06-25  0
12    a 2007-03-15  1
14    a 2008-06-21  2
21    b 2006-06-25  0
28    b 2007-03-15  1
30    b 2008-06-21  2
```

Comment: I have to say this is very easy to understand!Thanks to you.

Comment: I do you know this is my first approach I used `beg = np.array([['{}/7/01'.format(i),'{}/6/30'.format(i+1)] for i in range(2005,2010)])`  `index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(pd.to_datetime(beg[:,0]),pd.to_datetime(beg[:,1]))`. Yours  is better

Comment: @Tangfeifan Yw~ :-)

Comment: I knew grouper but not offset aliases. Its new to me and is fantastic