# Resample by custom annual frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I know I can use AS-JUL to resample annually starting in July 1st, but how can I do by a different date?

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
            value
date
2005-07-02      4
2005-09-20      7
2005-11-12      4
2005-12-31      0
2006-07-03      5
2006-06-25      6
2006-07-23      1
2006-09-28      8
2006-12-21      1
2006-12-27      9
2007-07-03      7
2007-09-21      0

In [12]: df.resample("AS-JUL").sum()
Out[12]:
            value
date
2005-07-01     26
2006-07-01     19
2007-07-01      7
```

I want the start date to be the 5th July, how can I resample by that?

Comment: So, this question boils down to you want a Custom Offset like `"AS-JUL"` but starting from the 5th.

Comment: Yeah!@AndyHayden I just want to along the idea of yours yeasterday!

Comment: @AndyHayden It means that if the date is` 2015-7-02` it will start from the `2014-7-05`

Comment: yes, I will update to a cleaner example for you

Answer (score 3):

You could subtract 4 days, resample, then add the 4 days back... but this is kind of horrible:

```
In [11]: data2.index = data2.index - pd.offsets.Day(4)

In [12]: res = data2.resample("AS-JUL").sum()

In [13]: res.index = res.index + pd.offsets.Day(4)

In [14]: res
Out[14]:  
           value
date    
2004-07-05  4
2005-07-05  22
2006-07-05  26
2007-07-05  12
```

Comment: I am expecting a better solution here, but will throw this down :)

Comment: Actually you this fix it the question,but I want to firgure out how to continue in last question!

Comment: @Tangfeifan same idea applies: subtract 4 days from date column, do the AS-JUL thing, add 4 days to the result.

Comment: Not much about custom date start of the year in the source too. You can do feature request na?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a date offset i.e

```
data2['date'].map(to_offset('AS-JUL')) +  pd.DateOffset(days=4)
```

Output :

```
0    2006-07-05
1    2006-07-05
2    2006-07-05
3    2006-07-05
4    2006-07-05
5    2006-07-05
6    2007-07-05
7    2007-07-05
```

Comment: This just changes the label, but doesn't change the actual underlying resample (ie. will group the 4th July as the 5th, rather than the previous "year"). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871173/resample-by-custom-annual-frequency#comment80689658_46871173

Comment: @AndyHayden is right the groupby result is wrong as I change the data